# Is the iPhone Store ID necessary for Facebook mobile app request being seen in notifications?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-app-requests

I've tried to use the Facebook iOS dialog request, but unfortunately the request is not showing up in the Facebook Mobile App.

Since then, I've tried to add a Page Canevas (with the same Facebook app id) and magically I've been able to receive notifications on my Facebook Internet account ("XXXX sent you a request"), but nothing in the Facebook Mobile App.

I've heard that I need an iPhone store ID to solve my problem.
Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, I put an iPhone store id (not my own but an other app's) and suddenly I got the notification on my mobile :)

Great day !